# Advanced Push Targeting with Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm targeting my push notifications to users within a certain distance of an event. I've got this working with a hard coded distance value as follows:

```
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.withinMiles("location", geoPoint, 10.0);
```

The issue is, I want the user to be able to specify their "range" for receiving these notifications. I have this preference saved in the user Installation object, but can't figure out how to go about pushing to users where the event is within their "distance preference" of miles. Is this possible?

Comment: what happens when you replace the 10 with the "distance preference"?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know how to add that as part of the query. If it were the distance preference of the user who triggers the push notification, the query would be pretty simple. What I'm aiming for is that the distance preference will be different for every one of the recipients of the notification. Maybe someone has chosen to opt-in to notifications of events within 100 miles, while others won't receive notifications of any events more than 20 miles away.